# Erlang : variable '_' is unbound

Tags: erl

I'm trying to use "_" in Case but I'm missing some thing.
What i'm doing is :

```
case (Packet =:= #xmlel{name = <<"message">>, attrs = [_, {<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}], children = _}) of
    true ->
        ?INFO_MSG("True ###### Packet ~p", [Packet]);
    _ ->
        ?INFO_MSG("False ###### Packet ~p", [Packet])
end,
```

And the error is : variable '_' is unbound.

I want this variable "_" to mean in this function every thing.

Like -->

```
attrs = [Whatever, {<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}]

children = Whatever
```

How can I do it? thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

You cannot use '_' on the right of '='

You can only put it on the left of the '='

e.g.

`{_,4} = {x,y}` (correct)

`{x,y} = {_,4}` (wrong)

Comment: Ok, is there any thing mean "Whatever" can I use it ?

Like : Packet = {xmlel, <<"message">>, [{<<"to">>,<<"ttt@ttt.ttt">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}], []}

I want something mean everything in Erlang Like

Packet == #xmlel{name = <<"message">>, attrs = [WhatEever, {<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}], children = WhatEever})

Comment: I do not fully understand that. '_' means match everything. _=1 and _=2 will always pass. However a = 1 and a = 2 will crash.

Comment: I think I got what u mean. Basically, this is not the correct way to go, and Erlang does not support that for you. Pattern=Expression will check and match for you, you cannot put unknown stuff on the right of =. This is not the design of Erlang

Comment: thank you. Can I know if some text count something like :

te = "hi how are you today."
if te == "hi" ->

Comment: case Expression of
    Pattern1 -> XXOO;
    Pattern2 -> OOXX;
    _ -> XXXX
end,
if X<1 -> XX;
   X>10 -> OO;
   true -> XXOO
end